# Matchers.refEq() in JUnit compares the references of objects

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito

I'm trying to verify if the object that I created in my test method and the actual object has the same values in all the fields. I have used Matchers.refEq() to verify that. In my code, the actual references of the two objects are getting verified and not the field values as opposed to what the documentation says for Matchers.refEq().

What is wrong with the below test case?

```
@Test
public void sendEmailMsgTest() throws MessagingException{

    PowerMockito.mockStatic(Transport.class);
    PowerMockito.doNothing().when(Transport.class);
    Transport.send(Matchers.any(MimeMessage.class));

    Properties systemProperties = System.getProperties();
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(systemProperties);
    session.setDebug(debug);
    MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
    mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(sendFrom));
    mimeMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(
            validEmailAddress));
    mimeMessage.setSubject("HTML/CSS grade report");
    mimeMessage.setSentDate(new Date());
    final BodyPart textBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    textBodyPart
            .setText("Here is your score card for the HTML/CSS assessment");
    final BodyPart fileBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    final DataSource source = new FileDataSource(outputFile);
    fileBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    fileBodyPart.setFileName(new File(outputFile).getName());
    final Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    multipart.addBodyPart(textBodyPart);
    multipart.addBodyPart(fileBodyPart);
    mimeMessage.setContent(multipart);

    WriteGradeReportUtil.emailGrade(validEmailAddress, outputFile);
    Mockito.verify(Transport.class);
    Transport.send(Matchers.refEq(mimeMessage));
}
```

Method I'm trying to test :

```
static void emailGrade(){
//Some code
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(sendFrom));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(
                    sendTo));
            message.setSubject("HTML/CSS grade report");
            message.setSentDate(new Date());
            final BodyPart textBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            textBodyPart
                    .setText("Here is your score card for the HTML/CSS assessment");
            final BodyPart fileBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            final DataSource source = new FileDataSource(outputFile);
            fileBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            fileBodyPart.setFileName(new File(outputFile).getName());
            final Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            multipart.addBodyPart(textBodyPart);
            multipart.addBodyPart(fileBodyPart);
            message.setContent(multipart);
            Transport.send(message);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Mockito 1.x uses internally an hamcrest matcher and internally the matcher uses the Apache commons `org.mockito.internal.matchers.apachecommons.EqualsBuilder#reflectionEquals(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.String[])`. Mockito 2.x directly uses the Apache commons `org.mockito.internal.matchers.apachecommons.EqualsBuilder#reflectionEquals(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.String[])`

So if this call says the objects are not equal, maybe one of your fields is simply not equal.

Also note the Mockito javadoc warns you : `<b>Warning</b> The equality check is shallow!` maybe these fields don't implement `equals` as well, hence they cannot be equal.

---

OUtside the scope of this answer I'd like to make a remark on the snippet of the code. It is difficult to understand and then to refactor. One of the motto of mocker is *to not mock types you don't own*. You should instead use a mock mail server — there are plenty out there — and send the mail directly there.